# Should I use nofollow on links to my other sites?

Tags: seo, html, nofollow

I have a portfolio page, which includes websites that I made with links to them. Should I make nofollow links to them? Or does having do-follow links help me?

Comment: Why are you considering `nofollow`?

Answer (score 0):

A natural link structure does also include follow links.

But I would initial link with "nofollow" and only special customers or projects with "follow".

Comment: Ok, got it. But if that site has backlinks to my site it's worth sticking with dofollows, right? I'm not 100% sure how nofollow and dofollow links work.

Comment: dofollow: Google will follow this link and forward the "page power/page authority"
nofollow: Google will not forward the "page power/page authority"

note: in both situations your "page power" for each link will be divided by sum of all exisitng links on this page (nofollow + follow). So no benfit for you if you use only nofollow and try to keep the "page power"